# Increase i by + 1 for every time it loops

Tags: python, loops

I'm fresh to programming, and decided to try out Python to complete past papers from my exam board at school,

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to have i increase by + 1 each time the loop runs,

what I expect to see is "...station 1", "...station 2", "...station 3" and so forth,

```py
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input("Enter miles at charging station " + (i + 1)))
```

Comment: This already works if you correct the problem the error mentions. Also, when you get errors, include them in the question.

Comment: str(i + 1) helped, thanks, I should have mentioned the error, sorry

Comment: Its usually best to post the entire traceback message. We see them all the time. Well, those of us who write bugs do, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As python begins counting from zero, you would likely just have to add one to it (i+1).
As for concatenating it to the string, you have plenty of options. Firstly, you can do it using the `+` operator. Keep in mind this will throw an error if it is not a string that is trying to be concatenated, so you'll have to use the `str` function. Example:

```
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input("Enter miles at charging station " + str(i + 1) + ": "))
```

You can also use f-strings, which are regarded as cleaner by most people. Example:

```
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input(f"Enter miles at charging station {i + 1}: "))
```

Another way you can do this is by using the modulus operator, where the number replaces the `%d`, which represents a decimal integer. This will not work with floats (use `%f`). Example:

```
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input("Enter miles at charging station %d: " % (i + 1)))
```

Instead, you can convert it to a string beforehand. Then you use `%s` for string. This will make it work with floats. But judging by the `int()` at the end, I'm guessing you do not want to work with floats. Example:

```
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input("Enter miles at charging station %s: " % str(i + 1)))
```

It is also generally better to use snake_case instead of camelCase in python, so `numStations` would become `num_stations`. This is completely optional though.

It is also important to add a try, except block so the program does not crash when the number can not be turned into an integer.

An example of this:

```
for i in range(numStations):
    while ...: # A forever loop.
        try:
            currentMiles = int(input("Enter miles at charging station %d: " % (i + 1))) # Asks for the miles.
            break # Break out of the forever loop.
        except:
            print("Invalid input, try again please.") # On error, try again.
```

This makes sure that if an error (or exception) occurs the user has to input the value again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first turn `i+1` into a string.

```py
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input("Enter miles at charging station " + str(i + 1)))
```

This should work as intended. However, it is generally better to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). These are more readable and efficient ways of string formatting, better than string concatenation, which requires turning each element into a string manually.

```py
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input(f"Enter miles at charging station {i + 1}"))
```

As you can see, this approach is cleaner and easier to understand.

Also, consider adding a colon to your input prompts for better user experience:

```py
for i in range(numStations):
    currentMiles = int(input(f"Enter miles at charging station {i + 1}: "))
```